# How to order a group of ships to protect a specific area?

Tags: homeworld

I just started playing Homeworld (Classic) and was wondering if there were any commands that could help with having a group of ships protect a specific area and attack anything that enters range of it? I know they added that to remastered but I was wondering if I was just missing something, or if thats just part of the gameplay is managing who your attacking when.

Answer (score 1):

Simply order your ships to move to the intended coordinates and leave them on the default Defensive Stance known as 'Neutral'. They will attack nearby enemies and try to dodge enemy weapons fire. Note; they will chase enemies if you put them on 'Aggressive' and not fire back on 'Evasive'.

The unit AI is of course fairly limited as is standard for an RTS. You may have better results micromanaging units especially against a human player.